# Riddle of the Unwanted Present

Tags: riddle

- The one who made it didn't want it
- The one who bought it didn't need it
- The one who received it didn't wish for it
- The one who used it never saw it

What was it?

Comment: This one is a really well-known riddle...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer:

> A coffin/tombstone

Obviously the man who made it doesn't want it! Who would **want** a [answer]?

The man that bought it didn't use it, if he needed it, he wouldn't have been in a state in which he was capable of buying anything.

The man who received it obviously didn't wish for it, refer back to the man who made it.

The man who used it couldn't have seen it, as he does not have the ability to do so!

Comment: Also, an urn for holding remains. I suppose answer could be anything that is used only in conjunction with a dead body.

Comment: Or a Coffin....

Comment: Doesn't apply to #hindus becuase we don't bury but burn the corpse.

Answer (score 0):

> A grave. The one who dug it didn't need it, the one who bought the spot didn't need to use it themself, the one who was put in the grave didn't want to be dead, the dead one never saw it (because they were dead)