# I just wish I wasn't needed. What am I?

Tags: riddle

When I'm needed, I wish I wasn't.

When I'm not needed I won't have what to do

What do I do, what am I?

**Clarificaton**

> Life still occurs, birth will ultimately result in death

**Hint** (Due to being put on hold for being 'too broad' I decided to ease this with the following)

> Think of someone who only has a job as long as people die unnatural deaths

**Hint #2**

> I'm the one that has to think about what the coroner tells me

Comment: Is the second sentence intentionally worded that way, or could you make it grammatically correct without ruining your riddle?

Comment: It's not incorrect, per say. The answer of this riddle is a person, who does something. Due to that activity, that person is something. (What does x do?, What is x?). Similar to what a Criminal does. I do crimes, I am a criminal.

Comment: That would be the 3rd sentence. I think @IanMacDonald means "When I'm not needed ...".

Comment: Bad formatting including a random incorreect comma. My apologies. Corrected now

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, but it still sounds wrong, and I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: It's pretty much as simplified as I can make it without devirtuating all the content.

Comment: @Sleafar and others: I think it might mean "When I'm not needed, I won't have ____ to do", since OP says "what do I do" in the next line. The identity AND function are the answer(s) to the riddle, here.

Comment: What makes it difficult is that most occupations will have "side" activities to do when not performing their primary function like cleaning, maintaining equipment, or paperwork/record keeping. Are we  looking for a job that actually does not have these, or are we ignoring those types of activities for the purpose of this question?

Comment: This reminds me an awful lot of [this riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/riddle-of-the-unwanted-present/2815), but I don't think it's duplicate, just similar.

Comment: ^True, but not an object =)

Comment: any guide on my answer? I guess it perfectly fits your riddle (which I believe is really broad). if not can you explain why?

Comment: It's essentially the same thing I said to Irishpanda's answer. It's close, but, for that to be true, deaths would need to stop occuring. I added a small clarification "Life still occurs, birth will ultimately result in death". So it cannot be a coroner nor an undertaker, as their job will always be needed. But it's still close. And, it does involve death

Comment: What does "I won't have what to do" mean? Seems nonsensical.

Comment: @AE If you're a teacher, and suddenly everyone stops going to school (there are no more students), you won't have what to do, because you can no longer teach

Comment: Due to being put on hold I added an extremely strong hint

Comment: @Oak perhaps you mean "not have anything to do"?

Comment: @AE. It's one way to put it. However, despite not being fluent, this form isn't wrong either. "Not have anything to do" means that you won't have anything to do. This form hints that, you won't have /what/ (eg: Studying/Activity) to do

Comment: Considering this has been put on hold, for seemingly selfish motives, and hasn't been reopened even though it has been edited to narrow even further. Not forgetting that this isn't the first riddle I've seen being put on hold for having 3-5 possible answers, I decided that I'll just post the answer here. The Answer is a Crime Scene Investigator / Anyone who deals with crimes. As long as there's crimes, they are needed, but they fight against crime so they don't want it. Crimes cease to exist, so does their 'what' to do in life.

Comment: @Oak You can answer your own question and accept your own answer, instead of leaving it here at the bottom of the comments.  Since the question has just been reopened, it would be best to show people that it has been "solved", instead of trusting everyone to find your comment.

Comment: Not when it's locked

Comment: @Oak A crime scene investigator could still have a job investigating non-murder crimes

Comment: But not if there were no crimes

Answer (score 5):

When I'm needed, I wish I wasn't.

> Not happy about killing/beheading/hanging people

When I'm not needed I won't have what to do

> But, If i won't have to execute anyone, I'll be jobless.

What do I do, what am I?

> Executioner

Comment: It's not the correct answer, but the strongest answer so far. It fits perfectly, and, despite not being the answer, it could easily be it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> A medical examiner/coroner? Since someone has to die for his services to be needed (performing autopsies), one would hope he would not want to be needed. Also, if no one dies, he has nothing to do.

Comment: It is a close guess, however coroners and medical examiners are doctors, and can exercise other medical activities. Not to mention that death occurs naturally. The answer to the riddle is something that wouldn't require the natural order to be changed. However, it's close to the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

What do I do, what am I?

> You are an "undertaker", who takes care of dead people

When I'm needed, I wish I wasn't.

> No one wants to take care of dead people because seeing them is sad or there can be other self reasons.

When I'm not needed I won't have what to do

> When there are no bodies, you are not needed and won't have any job to do